# Keras_Segmentation VGG-Unet Causes AttributeError: 'Functional' object has no attribute 'output_width'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-segmentation, vgg-net

I created a model with the [image-segmentation-keras library](https://github.com/divamgupta/image-segmentation-keras) by initializing it as such:

```
import keras_segmentation
from keras_segmentation.models.unet import vgg_unet
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input

model = vgg_unet(n_classes=21 ,  input_height=256, input_width=448)
```

I then train it as such:

```
model.train(
    train_images =  "/content/drive/MyDrive/imgs_train/",
    train_annotations = "/content/drive/MyDrive/masks_train/",
    val_images =  "/content/drive/MyDrive/mgs_validation/",
    val_annotations = "/content/drive/MyDrive/masks_validation/",
    checkpoints_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/tmp/vgg_unet_1" , 
    epochs=28,validate=True,callbacks = [myCallback])

model.load_weights('checkpoint_filepath')
```

And save it like so:

```
model.save('/content/drive/MyDrive/vgg_unet_segmentation.h5')
```

Then load it like so:

```
model = load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/vgg_unet_segmentation.h5'')
```

However, when I try to make a prediction by doing `out = model.predict_segmentation(inp=inp, out_fname="/tmp/out.png")`, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Functional' object has no attribute 'predict_segmentation'
```

So to solve this issue I did the following:

```
from types import MethodType
model = load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/vgg_unet_segmentation.h5'')
model.predict_segmentation = MethodType(keras_segmentation.predict.predict, model)
```

However, this lead to another issue which I haven't been able to resolve:

```
[<ipython-input-7-a4b7d02cd9a2>](https://localhost:8080/#) in <module>()
      4 out = model.predict_segmentation(
      5     inp=inp,
----> 6     out_fname="/tmp/out.png")

[/content/image-segmentation-keras/keras_segmentation/predict.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in predict(model, inp, out_fname, checkpoints_path, overlay_img, class_names, show_legends, colors, prediction_width, prediction_height, read_image_type)
    148     assert (len(inp.shape) == 3 or len(inp.shape) == 1 or len(inp.shape) == 4), "Image should be h,w,3 "
    149 
--> 150     output_width = model.output_width
    151     output_height = model.output_height
    152     input_width = model.input_width

AttributeError: 'Functional' object has no attribute 'output_width'
```

Any idea why this might be happening, and if so, how it can be resolved?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try model.predict() for the output like the following code :

```
prediction = (model.predict(test_img_input))
predicted_img=np.argmax(prediction, axis=3)[0,:,:]
plt.imshow(predicted_img)
```